# Uikit Dropdown for dynamically created (reactive) DOM in Meteor

Tags: meteor, getuikit

An app I'm building shows email accounts in a sidenav as a dropdown (or accordion) as described [here](http://getuikit.com/docs/nav.html).

The dropdown works fine when the data exist on load time, thanks to the [UIkit observer](http://getuikit.com/docs/documentation_javascript.html#dom-observe).

The code looks something like this (simlified):

```
<div id="app_wrapper" data-uk-observe>
    <ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-side uk-nav-parent-icon" data-uk-nav data-uk-observe>
        {{#each mailAccounts}}
        <li class="uk-parent ct-mail-account-side-nav-entry">
            <a href="#">user@domain.tld</a>
            <ul class="uk-nav-sub">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="uk-icon-inbox"></i> Inbox</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="uk-icon-folder"></i> Sent</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="uk-icon-folder"></i> Trash</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="uk-icon-folder"></i> Spam</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="uk-nav-divider"></li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

When adding new accounts through a meteor method, the entry appears yet the dropdown is stone dead. Only if the template is completely rerendered it comes to life. That usually requires a little detour to some other page where the menu doesn't exist.

- How can I make the observer aware of the change?
- Why doesn't the observer notice the change and apply it's magic to the newly created entry?
- Is there a way to manually assign the JavaScript dropdown magic to the newly created element?

UIkit Version: 2.19.0

Answer (score 0):

Meteor uses ractive variables to modify DOM at runtime. What this means is that your mailAccounts need to be a ractive variable. There are two cheap (in terms of effort) methods to achieve this

1. Define mailAccounts as a session variable
2. Have mailAccounts be part of a collection

There is a third way as well, if you don't mind writing  some more code. Use ractiveVar package and define mailAccounts as a reactiveVar.